# Saving and loading a dynamic gWidgets GUI

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I have a dynamic GUI created using gWidgets package in R (guiToolkit="RGtk2" if it matters). By dynamic I mean that form elements are created and removed while using the GUI. I wonder if there is a simple way to save the current GUI with all the current form elements and selected/typed values, and then load it later. Saving and loading a workspace doesn't seem to work for this kind of things, for example:

```
require (gWidgets)
options (guiToolkit="RGtk2")
win1 <- gwindow("Test")
svalue(win1) <- "Window 1"
win2 <- win1
svalue(win2) <- "Window 2"
visible(win1)=FALSE
visible(win2)=TRUE
```

Works fine, you can copy an object and it continues working under other variable name. But when you save the workspace and load it you get an error "assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed" when trying to execute last 2 lines. So, load() function doesn't recreate the object properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some kind of data structure that you use to describe your GUI, combined with  a function that builds the GUI based on this data structure. I would use `save` to save this data structure, allowing you to preform a `load` later, based on which you can rebuild your GUI.

Comment: All data structures are saved when a workspace is saved. Loading a workspace did not do any changes to the GUI.

Comment: When starting your GUI, you initialize it somewhere with a data structure telling how the GUI should be drawn, right? That data structure need to be saved and loaded. If you initialize your GUI statically, you need to change that first.

Comment: Ok, here is some sample code:
    require (gWidgets);
    options (guiToolkit="RGtk2");
    win1 <- gwindow("Test");
    svalue(win1) <- "Window 1";
    win2 <- win1;
    svalue(win2) <- "Window 2";
    visible(win1)=FALSE;
    visible(win2)=TRUE  

Works fine, meaning that you can copy an object and it continues working under other variable name. But when you save the workspace and load it you get an error when trying to execute last 2 lines. If you close the window after saving loading the workspace won't show it as well.

Comment: Could you add these details to your question?

Comment: The RGtk2 objects are pointers that don't get saved. The comment about saving a means to construct the GUI is the only way to do this -- you can't save the objects, but you can save some recipe to make them. Now, there is no natural format, such as XML, which is used by some of the toolkits.